# ReactJs - Como executar chamadas AJAX?

Tags: ajax, react

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto em `React` (primeira vez que estou trabalhando com `React`) e estou com dúvidas no momento de executar chamadas ao servidor, seja um `GET` ou `POST`.

Eu até consegui executar essa tarefa, porém de modo meio "limitado", pois não estou conseguindo enviar estrutura de datas mais complexas, como um objeto `JSON`.

Atualmente estou utilizando `fetch()`, deste modo:

```
// Funcionando normalmente dentro do esperado
fetch(DEFAULT_URL)
.then(function(response) {
    if ( response.status !== 200 ) {
        console.log('Status Code: ' +  response.status);
        return;
    }

    response.json().then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
})
```

Porém, ao executar um `POST` eu só consigo deste modo:

```
fetch(POST_URL, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
    },
    body: "name= Nome completo"
})
.then(function(response) {
    if ( response.status !== 200 ) {
        console.log('Status Code: ' +  response.status);
        return;
    }

    response.json().then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
})
```

O que não possibilita o envio de um objeto `JSON`, se utilizar ele apresenta erro e não executa a chamada.

---

Existe algum outro método, ou um método correto/melhor de se executar essas chamadas com `React`? Não precisa ser com `fetch`, só estou utilizando este método pois não consegui encontrar outro.

O objetivo seria tanto obter dados do banco de dados, como postagens de notícias, dados da empresa, etc. Bem como o envio de informações para cadastro no banco de dados, como cadastro de usuário, entre outros.

Comment: Eu uso o método ``$.ajax`` do jQuery ou as shorthands ``get``, ``post``, ``put`` e ``delete``. Na dúvida, troque de biblioteca de Ajax ou faça umas funções no braço mesmo. Ah! E React não tem nenhum método específico, mas é boa prática incluir chamadas dessas no ``componentDidMount``.

Comment: @Daniel Pretendo continuar somente usando React (ou algum plugin para o mesmo). Não pretendo fazer load de jQuery somente para executar as chamadas ajax. Alguma outra sugestão? Sobre o local de onde inserir as chamadas eu já li alguns materiais que guiam para isso.

Comment: Então, acho super válido criar umas funções simples usando o XMLHttpRequest logo. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Ou então: ao invés de mandar um objeto JSON, manda só uma string usando o ``JSON.Stringify `` no objeto que você quer mandar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apesar de recomendações quanto ao uso do método `fetch`, optei por utilizar outro serviço de chamadas AJAX, devido a questões de compatibilidade e uso de `promise`. O serviço que estou utilizando é o [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) que foi extremamente fácil de integrar ao projeto e possui um uso muito simples.

Tudo que precisei fazer foi o download do serviço, feito através do npm, e importação nos componentes que forem necessários, por exemplo:

```
import axios from "axios";

// Método GET
axios.get('/minha/url').then(function (response) {
    console.log('Success: ', response);

}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log('Error: ', error);
});

// Método POST
axios.post('/minha/outra/url', data).then(function (response) {
    console.log('Success: ', response);

}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log('Error: ', error);
});

// Múltiplas requisições
function carregaUsuario() {
    return axios.get('minha/url/usuario');
}

function carregaEndereco() {
    return axios.get('minha/url/endereco');
}

axios.all([carregaUsuario(), carregaEndereco()]).then(
    axios.spread(function (usuario, endereco) {
        // Retorno das requisições
    })
);
```